# Can you pop_back a vector and still use the iterator to the last element?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I wonder what happens if I have an iterator on the last element of the vector and do `pop_back`.

```cpp
std::set<int> s;
s.insert(5);

std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end();) {
    if (s.count(*it)) {
        std::swap(*it, v.back());
        v.pop_back();
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Code above works properly (`v` is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` after that block) at least with clang, but is it correct to check if `it == v.end()` if `it` is invalidated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your instincts are good; [`vector::pop_back` invalidates iterators and references to the last element](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.modifiers#3). If `it` is such an iterator, then it will be invalidated, and thus cannot be compared with `v.end()`.

It would be much better to fix this by using algorithms and the erase-remove idiom:

```
auto last_it = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const auto &val) {return s.count(val) != 0;});
v.erase(last_it, v.end());
```