# Invalidated iterator: Fixing a function with UB without losing efficiency

Tags: c++

Consider the following function:

```
template<class T>
void remove_unordered(std::vector<T>& vec, T const& val)
{
  auto it = begin(vec);
  while (it != end(vec)) {
   if (*it == val) {
     *it = std::move(vec.back());
     vec.pop_back();
   }
   else { ++it; }
  }
}
```

The problem is when `it` points to the last element and this element is removed. This invalidated the iterator and therefore this is UB. It should normally work because the iterator is actually the end.

Is there some way to fix my function without introducing many more checks?

[Can you pop_back a vector and still use the iterator to the last element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629086/can-you-pop-back-a-vector-and-still-use-the-iterator-to-the-last-element) basically asks for the same question. The answer does not fix the function in a way that is much less efficient though. So I am still wondering if there is a better way to not have UB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you pop\_back a vector and still use the iterator to the last element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629086/can-you-pop-back-a-vector-and-still-use-the-iterator-to-the-last-element)

Comment: On a side note, should you call a variable `first` if it doesn't always point to the first element of the container?

Comment: A common convention is to name your `first` variable `it` (short for `iterator`) instead.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann It can also be not-short for "it".

Comment: You do not seem to care about the order of the not-removed elements. In such case, have you considered using partitioning first followed by erasing?

Comment: Partition has ```O(n log n)``` swaps. My method has exactly ```r``` moves which is the number of to remove elements.

Comment: @Henk That's not true, at least for single-threaded partitioning: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition. Why would you need _O(n log n)_ for partitioning?

Comment: @Henk I don't see it there: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.partitions#8.1. The Cppereference says the same.

Comment: Yeah you are right. However, it can perform ```n``` swaps when one swap would be enough, for example if the first element should be deleted. Also it need two iterators.

Comment: TedLyngmo's answer to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893925/12345656) gives you what you want, you only need to resize at the end. One resize will probably be faster than many pop_backs, especially for trivial value_types since then both are just one writing one pointer for each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be a possible workaround although it does not look really nice and does little additional work:

```
template<class T>
void remove_unordered(std::vector<T>& vec, T const& val)
{
  if(vec.empty()) { return; }
  auto it = begin(vec);
  while (it+1 != end(vec)) {
   if (*it == val) {
     *it = std::move(vec.back());
     vec.pop_back();
   }
   else { ++it; }
  }

  if (*it == val) {
    vec.pop_back();
  }
}
```